# Problem with the ternary operator in fold

Tags: scala, ternary-operator

Consider a simple Collection, searching the min and max in one iteration:

```
val v = Vector (2, 1, 3, 5, 4)
val mima = (v(0), v(0))
val mami = (mima /: v) {case ((a, b), c) => if (c<a) (c, b) else if (c>b) (a, c) else (a, b)}
```

So far, so straight forward. 
If I replace the if/else with the ternary operator (X ? Y : Z), it doesn't work; I get an error:

```
    val mami = (mima /: v) {case ((a, b), c) => (c<a) ? (c, b) : (c>b) ? (a, c) : (a, b)}
<console>:1: ';' expected but : found.
```

at the last colon. Adding parens didn't help:

```
    val mami = (mima /: v) {case ((a, b), c) => (c<a) ? (c, b) : ((c>b) ? (a, c) : (a, b))}
```

Do I make a silly mistake or is there is a subtle problem with the nested ternary operator?

Hunting this problem down, it isn't related to folds, only:

```
if (c < 4) "small" else if (c > 8) "big" else "medium"
```

works

```
(c < 4) ? "small" : (c > 8) ? "big" : "medium"
```

fails the same way.

Comment: There is no ternary in Scala if you check the syntax doc

Comment: Some syntax recommendation, almost nobody uses the fold symbolic operator, and they are being removed in the latest Scala version. It would be better to just call `foldLeft` directly. Also the `;` before the `else if` is unnecessary and strange _(it confused me when reading the code)_.

Comment: the `?`is called ternary operator, not elvis operator. elvis operator is from kotlin (and I think swift as well) and it's `?:` - used for null safe operations https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

Answer (score 5):

Scala doesn't have a ternary operator, because it has `if` which works as expression, so you can do things like:

```
val result = if (c < 4) "small" else if (c > 8) "big" else "medium"
```

You can also use it in fold:

```
val mami = (mima /: v) {case ((a, b), c) => if (c<a) (c, b) else if (c>b) (a, c) else (a, b)) }
```

Comment: That suspicion arose to me, shortly after posting, and while testing, I started to remember, that I knew this once upon a time.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, sorry Guys!

The simple solution is: There is no elvis operator in Scala. :) Gee, how could I forget that?

```
(a < 4) ? foo : bar
```

isn't that much shorter than

```
if (a < 4) foo; else bar
```

and in contrast to Java, Scala returns a value from an if/else statement, hence you don't need it.

Comment: Just to let you know, what you're referring to as an elvis operator is actually a ternary operator. The elvis operator is a different thing. Also, the semicolon in your if/else statement is unnecessary.

Comment: Well, I agree that it is <b>a</b> ternary operator, and since there is (afaik) only one in Java, it can be called <b>the</b> ternary operator, but without knowing that there is only one ternary operator, it might a bit confusing. So if in fact in kotlin and swift the ?: is glued together to a single token, it makes more sense there to give it a unique name and to insist, that A ? B : C is something else, and Elvis hard to see. Maybe I'm totally misguided and didn't even see A ? B : C been refered to as elvis operator somewhere else, and the confusion is totally mine. I'll edit the question.